# When "--" is not needed?

Tags: excel-formula

"--" converts TRUE/FALSE to 1/0. I have found that sometimes "--" is not needed . Math can be done directly on TRUE/FALSE. The following is an example:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,(LEFT(C5:C400,1)="T")*(LEN(C5:C400)=6)*RIGHT(C5:C400,5),1)
```

Both "(LEFT(C5:C400,1)="T")" and "(LEN(C5:C400)=6)" give an array of TRUE/FALSE. However, this array can be used directly in multiplication without first being converted to 1/0.

When it is not necessary to convert TRUE/FALSE to 1/0 and math would still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--` is the same as `-1 * -1`.

Any time Math is done against a string or boolean that can be converted to a number Excel will make the conversion to the number.

`--` is just a shorter method when only one Boolean or number stored as a string is used.

`VALUE()` can be used in place, or `+ 0`, or `* 1`  Any math will do it.

If multiple numbers stored as string or multiple Booleans are added or Multiplied or Subtracted or Divided, then the conversion is done and the `--` is not needed.